# How to resolve class references in an external config file for grails war deployment?

Tags: grails, log4j, perf4j

I am using Grails 1.3.7. I build a war file & deploy it in tomcat. I have an external groovy configuration file that I use to set up logging. I added some perf4j logging appenders to the declaration, but now the configuration file fails to compile because it cannot resolve the fully-qualified class names.

The code looks like this:

```
log4j = {
    ...
    // file appender that writes out the URLs of the Google Chart API graphs generated by the performanceGraphAppender
    def performanceGraphFileAppender = new org.apache.log4j.FileAppender(
        fileName: "log/perfGraphs.log",
        layout: pattern(conversionPattern: '%m%n')
    )
    appender name: 'performanceGraphFileAppender', performanceGraphFileAppender

    // this appender creates the Google Chart API graphs
    def performanceGraphAppender = new org.perf4j.log4j.GraphingStatisticsAppender(
        graphType: 'Mean',      // possible options: Mean, Min, Max, StdDev, Count or TPS
        tagNamesToGraph: 'tag1,tag2,tag3',
        dataPointsPerGraph: 5
    )
    performanceGraphAppender.addAppender(performanceGraphFileAppender)
    appender name: 'performanceGraph', performanceGraphAppender

    ...
}
```

and the error message that's written out into the log is this:

```
script1317679813518843914255.groovy: 38: unable to resolve class org.perf4j.log4j.GraphingStatisticsAppender 
@ line 38, column 34.
    def performanceGraphAppender = new org.perf4j.log4j.GraphingStatisticsAppender(
```

The war file I am building contains all the required JARs. Any thoughts on how to get it to resolve the references?

Thanks,

Gene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a possibility that after deployment, it starts using log4j from tomcat. Take a look at `lib` folder, maybe it's contains log4j jars. If that's true - the it uses different classloader, that can't see your perf4j classes.

You can try to put your perf4j jars into tomcat's `lib`, probably it can fix this issue

Comment: That's interesting. I will give it a shot. I do wonder, though, how that works: the grails runtime is in the same WAR file as the perf4j files. Why wouldn't it find them? What am I missing?

Comment: When I put the perf4j and log4j jars into the tomcat/lib folder, the code seemed to run correctly. I wonder why it doesn't pick up the classes from the application WAR file.

Comment: it's problem of different classloaders. Seems, that tomcat had log4j classes somewhere else, not only your war (as log4j is used by most of projects), and JVM stated using it (= from different classloader). At same time per4j was only in your war, but classloader that contains log4j (= neighbour classloader) haven't access to your libs.

Comment: Before I put log4j into the lib folder, it wasn't resolving log4j classes mentioned in my logging.groovy file either. So its still a mystery to me.